# Optimizing MongoDB aggregate query on large Index objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

I have 20 Million objects in my MongoDb collection. Currently running on M30 MongoDb instance with 7.5Gb ram and 40Gb disk.

Data is stored in collection like this -

```
{
 _id:xxxxx,
 id : 1 (int),
 from : xxxxxxxx (int),
 to : xxxxxx (int),
 status : xx (int)
 .
 .
 .
 .
},
{

 _id:xxxxx,
 id : 2 (int),
 from : xxxxxxxx (int),
 to : xxxxxx (int),
 status : xx (int)
 .
 .
 .
 .
}
.
.
.
. and so on..
```

**id** is unique Index & **from** is a Index in this collection.

I am running a query to group 'to' and return me the max id and sort by max id with a given condition i.e 'from'

```
$collection->aggregate([
            ['$project' => ['id'=>1,'to'=>1,'from'=>1],
            [ '$match'=> [
                        '$and'=> 
                                [ 
                                    [ 'from'=> xxxxxxxxxx],
                                    [ 'status'=> xx ],
                                ] 
                        ] 
            ],
            ['$group' => [
                        '_id' => 
                                '$to',
                                'max_revision'=>['$max' => '$id'],
                        ]
            ],
            ['$sort' => ['max_revision' => -1]],
            ['$limit' => 20],

]);
```

Above query runs just fine (~2 sec) on small data set on Index **from** like for 50-100k of same 'from' value in collection. But for conditions like, for example if 2M objects are having same 'from' value, then it is taking over >10 sec to execute and giving the result.

A quick example,
case 1- same query runs under 2 sec if it is executed with **from** as 12345, As 12345 is present 50k times in the collection.

case 2- query takes over 10 sec if it executed with **from** as 98765, As 98765 is present 2M times in the collection.

Edit : Explained query below -

```
{
  "command": {
    "aggregate": "mycollection",
    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$project": {
          "id": 1,
          "to": 1,
          "from": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "$and": [
            {
              "from": {
                "$numberLong": "12345"
              }
            },
            {
              "status": 22
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "$to",
          "max_revision": {
            "$max": "$id"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$sort": {
          "max_revision": -1
        }
      },
      {
        "$limit": 20
      }
    ],
    "allowDiskUse": false,
    "cursor": {},
    "$db": "mongo_jc",
    "lsid": {
      "id": {
        "$binary": "8LktsSkpTjOzF3GIC+m1DA==",
        "$type": "03"
      }
    },
    "$clusterTime": {
      "clusterTime": {
        "$timestamp": {
          "t": 1597230985,
          "i": 1
        }
      },
      "signature": {
        "hash": {
          "$binary": "PHh4eHh4eD4=",
          "$type": "00"
        },
        "keyId": {
          "$numberLong": "6859724943999893507"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "planSummary": [
    {
      "IXSCAN": {
        "from": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "keysExamined": 1246529,
  "docsExamined": 1246529,
  "hasSortStage": 1,
  "cursorExhausted": 1,
  "numYields": 9747,
  "nreturned": 0,
  "queryHash": "29DAFB9E",
  "planCacheKey": "F5EBA6AE",
  "reslen": 231,
  "locks": {
    "ReplicationStateTransition": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "w": 9847
      }
    },
    "Global": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 9847
      }
    },
    "Database": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 9847
      }
    },
    "Collection": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 9847
      }
    },
    "Mutex": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 100
      }
    }
  },
  "storage": {
    "data": {
      "bytesRead": {
        "$numberLong": "6011370213"
      },
      "timeReadingMicros": 4350129
    },
    "timeWaitingMicros": {
      "cache": 2203
    }
  },
  "protocol": "op_msg",
  "millis": 8548
}
```

Comment: Some relevant info: [Query Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/query-optimization/index.html) - see topic Selectivity _and_ [Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/index.html).

Comment: Add explained query plan to question.

Comment: @D.SM added the gist of explained query

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case the mongod query executor can use an index for the initial match, but not for the sort.

If you were to reorder and modify the stages a bit, it could use an index on `{from:1, status:1, id:1}` for both matching and sorting:

```
$collection->aggregate([
            [ '$match'=> [
                        '$and'=> 
                                [ 
                                    [ 'from'=> xxxxxxxxxx],
                                    [ 'status'=> xx ],
                                ] 
                        ] 
            ],
            ['$sort' => ['id' => -1]],
            ['$project' => ['id'=>1,'to'=>1,'from'=>1],
            ['$group' => [
                        '_id' => '$to',
                        'max_revision'=>['$first' => '$id'],
                      ]
            ],
            ['$limit' => 20],

]);
```

This way the it should be able to combine the `$match` and `$sort` stages into a single index scan.

Comment: Makes sense but this makes the pipeline go beyond 100 Mb of ram usage and finally run on Disk for sorting. Still taking >10 sec to execute.
Profiler gist - https://gist.github.com/TomarAditya/30444b158613b2b967fafb11860b8664

Comment: bah, I typo'd - when sorting before the `$group`, need to use the name the field has before grouping.  Edited now.  Also, you will need to create a compound index on `{from:1, status:1, id:1}`